# kotlin, how dynamically change the for loop pace

Tags: for-loop, kotlin

sometime based on some condition it may want to jump (or move forward) a few steps inside the for loop,

how to do it is kolin?

a simplified use case:

```
val datArray  = arrayOf(1, 2, 3......)

/**
 * start from the index to process some data, return how many data has been 
   consumed
*/
fun processData_1(startIndex: Int) : Int  {
   // process dataArray starting from the index of startIndex
   // return the data it has processed
}
fun processData_2(startIndex: Int) : Int  {
   // process dataArray starting from the index of startIndex
   // return the data it has processed
}
```

in Java it could be:

```
for (int i=0; i<datArray.lenght-1; i++) {
   int processed = processData_1(i);
   i += processed; // jump a few steps for those have been processed, then start 2nd process
   if (i<datArray.lenght-1) { 
       processed = processData_2(i);
       i += processed;
   }
}
```

How to do it in kotlin?

```
for(i in array.indices){
  val processed = processData(i);
  // todo
}
```

Comment: There is always good old `while`...

Comment: I don't think it's a clean solution to change the counter variable manually, use while instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `while`:

```
var i = 0

while (i < datArray.length - 1) {
    var processed = processData_1(i)
    i += processed // jump a few steps for those have been processed, then start 2nd process
    if (i < datArray.length - 1) {
        processed = processData_2(i)
        i += processed
    }
    i++
}
```

Comment: use `datArray.length` insted of `datArray.length - 1`. Because this is lessThan only not lessThan and equalTo

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `continue` as stated in the Kotlin docs here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html

Example:

```
val names = arrayOf("james", "john", "jim", "jacob", "johan")
for (name in names) {
    if(name.length <= 4) continue
    println(name)
}
```

This would only print names longer than 4 characters (as it skips names with a length of 4 and below)

Edit: this only skips one iteration at a time. So if you want to skip multiple, you could store the process state somewhere else and check the status for each iteration.